# FIlter object array by select option box in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have 2 select option box and with these selected values, I want to find a data from object array data.

I could get value data in array like this

```
['black','7']
```

And array data want to filter is like this.

```
array[0:{id:01,name: "Glove black size7" , attributes:{d001:value:black,  d002:value:7}},
      1:{id:01,name: "Glove pink size7" , attributes:{d001:value:pink,  d002:value:7}]
```

```js
//in jquery page I run onChange function

$(document).on('change', '.variant select', function(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
  var select = $(this).val();
  var attribute = a.target.name;
  var selectedVals = $('select').map(function() { return this.value; }).get(); 
  changeAttribute(select, attribute, selectedVal);

})

function changeAttribute(select, attribute, selectedVal) {

  //Get data from element and get loop array data which I want to filter
  var variant = JSON.parse($('.variant').attr('data-value'));
  for (var i = 1; i < variant.length; i++) {

    // Inside here I want to filter object array data and find a data

  }
```

```html
<div class="variant">
  <select name="d001" id="attribute">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
  </select>

  <select name="d002" id="attribute">
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `data-value` in the HTML?

Comment: What is `$("option:selected").val()` supposed to be? How are you expecting it to be different from `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Why doesn't `changeAttribute` use any of its parameters?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do in your code. There's nothing that looks like filtering.

Comment: $("option:selected").val() makes an array and put 2 selected data from 2 select options. like this. ['black','7']

Comment: And with this array data, i want to find a data from attribute array which is matching with data-value.

Comment: No it doesn't. `.val()` only returns an array if you call it on a multiselect.

Comment: `$("option:selected").val()` returns the value of the first selected option in the page.

Comment: Ok then how should I do that?

Comment: To get an array of the values of all the selects, use `var selectedVals = $('select').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`

Comment: Then how to filter object array with this array data?

Comment: array[0:{id:01,name: "Glove black size7" , attributes:{d001:value:black,  d002:value:7}},
      1:{id:01,name: "Glove pink size7" , attributes:{d001:value:pink,  d002:value:7}]

Comment: `{d001:value:black,  d002:value:7}` is not a valid object. Objects are `{key: value, key: value, ...}`. There's no `key:value:value` in objects. I assume it's just `{d001:black,  d002:7}`

Comment: `array.filter(el => el.attributes.d001 == d001 && el.attributes.d002 == d002)`